# IOS swift How can I get my SubView to appear below my SearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, addsubview

I have a UISearchBar embedded within a form so what I am trying to do is once someone clicks on the SearchBar I want a TableView to popup as a subView . I have that working correctly however I would like the SubView to appear under the SearchBar so that Users can keep searching, my SubView takes over the entire page . Here is how I am trying to get the functionality to work: *Trulia App* .
 Notice the searchBar with the corresponding View now if you click on the SearchBar a subView appears right below the SearchBar . As stated before for me everything is working except that the subView takes over the whole page and does not appear underneath the SearchBar. This is my code , the third image is my storyBoard below and this is my code

```
       class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var Location: UISearchBar!
       func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)

        let Popup = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "zip_searches") as! ExampleTableViewController
        self.addChildViewController(Popup)
        Popup.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(Popup.view)
        Popup.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        return true
    }
}
```

[[image: Main Page[1]]

[image: SubView]

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found an easy solution to my problem. You simply have a SearchBar at the top then you create a second UIView and put it underneath your SearchBar. Then you connect that new UIView such as

```
@IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
```

then when it comes to the frame portion you simply do this

```
Popup.view.frame = self.view2.frame
```

That is it when you click on SearchBar the View2 will act as a popup and cover everything underneath the searchBar .

Answer (score 1):

iOS has UISearchController for this.  Here is code to add and constrain the search bar to an existing container view in your story board as well as to set a tableViewController to show when the user starts typing.

```
    locationSearchResultTableViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: LocationSearchResultTableViewController.self)) as! LocationSearchResultTableViewController
    locationSearchResultTableViewController.delegate = self
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchResultTableViewController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchResultTableViewController
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    searchContainer.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    searchController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let attributes: [NSLayoutAttribute] = [.top, .bottom, .left, .right]
    attributes.forEach { NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.searchController.searchBar, attribute: $0, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: searchController.searchBar.superview, attribute: $0, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, I will now incorporate that in